# How to use the path from $_SERVER variable, modify it and assign it to some variable in PHP?

Tags: php, global-variables, server-variables

As we know `$_SERVER` array is wriiten by web server and it's not a good practice to make any change in it. Now the scenario is I'm using this `$_SERVER` array in my project and I want to temporarily change the value of one of array elements of `$_SERVER` array. I want to assign this temporarilychanged value to some variable say `$redirection_path`. How to do this?
Following is the array element I have after printing the `$_SERVER` array:

```
Array
(
  [SCRIPT_NAME] => /my-project-folder/web/control/login.php
)
```

Now I want to take the path value from above array and change it to following value:

```
$redirection_path = /my-project-folder/web/control/modules/bakery/cake.php
```

But while doing this the actual `$_SERVER` array should not get affected. How should I do this in an optimum manner? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [**`dirname`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php) to extract the parent path of `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']` and append your new subpath to it.

```
$redirection_path = dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']).'/modules/bakery/cake.php';
```